# How to use R studio on a remote server

Tags: r, server, rstudio

Currently, i use R studio on my desktop, with all analysis run using my desktop machine
Performance for this is really poor, so i'm getting an external server that is more powerful dedicated for R jobs

I really like the Rstudio IDE, Is there a way I can connect Rstudio on my desktop to run R on the external server?
I want to be able to use it in the same way as I use my desktop version of R, so i can view my graphs etc

Comment: Have you tried connecting with a web browser?

Answer (score 9):

RStudio Server is what you need. You can download it here:

https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server-2/

Install it on your external server; then from your desktop (or from any other machine!) you can connect to the server in a web browser and use RStudio inside the web browser. RStudio Server shares a great deal of code with the desktop version so the interface will be nearly identical to what you're accustomed to.

Comment: is this setup you described free?

Comment: There are professional and open source versions. For personal use, the open source version will almost certainly be enough!

Comment: update for the link  > https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/#rstudio-server

Comment: Can I connect my Rstudio Desktop to a remote Rstudio Server? Or the server can only be accessed from a web browser?

Comment: @skan RStudio Desktop Pro can connect to the RStudio Server as described [here](https://posit.co/blog/rstudio-1-3-preview-desktop-pro/); as of writing, I don't believe you can from the free version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you sign up with Amazon AWS you can use Rstudio Server and control it from your desktop pretty easily. Give this site a read and see what you can do!

http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/

If you have your own server at work or the university, you can install the server there and use a vm window to log in from anywhere.